# Dart: How to find number of days between two dates excluding Weekend or Predicate

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to calculate number of days between two dates in Dart. 
There is built in function for that.

```
 leaveEndDate.difference(leaveStartDate).inDays
```

But I do not want weekends to be included. 
Is there any way I can traverse between these 2 Dates or I can just exclude weekends.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have no other choice than looping through all the days to check if this is a weekend day or not :

```dart
void main() {
  DateTime date1 = DateTime(2019, 12, 01);
  DateTime date2 = DateTime(2019, 12, 31);

  print(getDifferenceWithoutWeekends(date1, date2));
}

int getDifferenceWithoutWeekends(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
  int nbDays = 0;
  DateTime currentDay = startDate;
  while (currentDay.isBefore(endDate)) {
    currentDay = currentDay.add(Duration(days: 1));
    if (currentDay.weekday != DateTime.saturday && currentDay.weekday != DateTime.sunday) {
      nbDays += 1;
    }
  }
  return nbDays;
}
```

Result :

> 22

EDIT :

Another solution, not sure it is faster but can be useful if you need to identify the dates (you could return `list<DateTime>` instead of `List<int>` to see which day is a weekend day).

Here I build each days between the 2 dates and return 1 if this is not a weekend day, then sum the list :

```dart
void main() {
  DateTime startDate = DateTime(2019, 12, 01);
  DateTime endDate = DateTime(2019, 12, 31);

  int nbDays = endDate.difference(startDate).inDays + 1;

  List<int> days = List.generate(nbDays, (index) {
    int weekDay = DateTime(startDate.year, startDate.month, startDate.day + (index)).weekday;
    if (weekDay != DateTime.saturday && weekDay != DateTime.sunday) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  print(days.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Yann39. in the mean time I also prepared a small function and it is exactly similar to your approach. let see if we see more better solution. :)

Comment: @Yann39 I try your Edit answer in dartpad, the result not same with your first answer. your second answer will return 21.

Comment: @ZeffryReynando Good point Zeffry, you're right, this is because the difference between the two dates is 30 (not 31), so it does not represent the real number of days. And as `List.generate` generates items for each index in the range [0 .. length - 1], this result in missing last day in the list... So either use `int nbDays = endDate.difference(startDate).inDays + 1;` or `List.generate(nbDays + 1, (index) { ... }`. I have edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I have also prepared a function which will traverse to all dates between two dates in Dart and will calculate number of days inBetween.

```
int calculateDaysBetween(DateTime mStartDate, DateTime mEndDate) {


int leaveDays = mEndDate.difference(mStartDate).inDays + 1;
int leaveBalance = 0;
var mTempDateTime =
DateTime(mStartDate.year, mStartDate.month, mStartDate.day);

for (int i = 0; i < leaveDays; i++) {
    mTempDateTime = DateTime(
    mTempDateTime.year, mTempDateTime.month, mTempDateTime.day + 1);

    if (mTempDateTime.weekday == DateTime.friday ||
    mTempDateTime.weekday == DateTime.saturday) {

    print('is weekend');
} else {
  leaveBalance++;
}

print(mTempDateTime);

}

// Total number of days between two dates excluding weekends.
return leaveBalance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improve @Developine Answer and make it more reusable , I make 2 function.

- 1.Calculate Total Days Of Month
- 2.Calculate TotalWeekDayOfMonth

#### Get Total Days Of Month

```
  int totalDaysOfMonth(int month, int year) {
    final result = (month < 12) ? DateTime(year, month + 1, 0) : DateTime(year + 1, 1, 0);
    return result.day;
  }
```

#### Get Total WeekDay Of Month

```
  int totalWeekDayOfMonth(int year, int month, {int day = 1}) {
    int totalDayOfMonth = totalDaysOfMonth(year, month);
    int result = 0;
    DateTime tempDateTime = DateTime(year, month, day);
    for (int i = day; i <= totalDayOfMonth; i++) {
      tempDateTime = DateTime(tempDateTime.year, tempDateTime.month, i);
      if (tempDateTime.weekday == DateTime.saturday || tempDateTime.weekday == DateTime.sunday) {
        print('is weekend');
      } else {
        result++;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

#### How To Use It

```
void main(){
  final resultWithoutDay = totalWeekDayOfMonth(2019,12);
  final resultWithDay = totalWeekDayOfMonth(2019,12,day: 16);
  print("Without Day $resultWithoutDay"); // 22
  print("With Day $resultWithDay"); // 12
}
```